# Find and replace words and special characters from specific files from linux

Tags: sed, replace, grep, special-characters

I have some multiple gnuplot files, and I wish to find and replace "set xrange [0:20]" to "set xrange [0:3]" for series of files of "gnuplot_RTre_*.gnplt" in current directory. I found how to swap specific strings from all files from folder, but not only for specific files including special characters.

So I tried

```
find . -type f -name "gnuplot_RTre_*.gnplt" -exec sed -i 's/set xrange [0:20]/set xrange [0:3]/g' {} +
```

It doesn't make an error, but it swaps nothing from those files. So I tried to escape special characters using backslash

```
find . -type f -name "gnuplot_RTre_*.gnplt" -exec sed -i 's/set xrange \\[\\0\\:\\20\\]\\/set xrange \\[\\0\\:\\3\\]\\/g' {} +
```

Still not working, no error, but no swapping.

I also tried

```
grep -rl 'set xrange [0:20]' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/set xrange [0:20]/set xrange [0:3]/g' gnuplot_RTre_*.gnplt
```

But it is not working as well.

I think my commands are wrong with special character escaping or file selection, but not sure how to solve this issue. Need some helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra backslashes to escape special characters. Please try:

```
# find . -type f -name "gnuplot_RTre_*.gnplt" -exec sed -i 's/set xrange \[0:20]/set xrange \[0:3]/g' {} +
# The backslash in the REPLACEMENT above is unnecessary, although harmless.
# Please adopt the following instead.
find . -type f -name "gnuplot_RTre_*.gnplt" -exec sed -i 's/set xrange \[0:20]/set xrange [0:3]/g' {} +
```

In `sed`, the characters `$.*[\^` need to be escaped with a backslash to be treated as literal.

[EDIT]
The right square bracket `"]"` is usually not a special character in regex and
you do not have to esacape it:

```
echo "[abc]" | sed 's/]/*/g'
=> [abc*
```

But `"]"` behaves as a metacharacter if preceded by an unescaped left square bracket `"["` to compose a `character class`.

```
echo "[abc]abc" | sed 's/[abc]/*/g'
=> [***]***
```

In order to make `"["` to be literal, we need to escape it.

```
echo "[abc]abc" | sed 's/\[abc]/*/g'
=> *abc
```

`"]"` can be also escaped just for visual symmetricity.

```
echo "[abc]abc" | sed 's/\[abc\]/*/g'
=> *abc
```

Comment: Thank you, that was simpler than I expected. I thought I need to escape all special characters in here, which is '[', ']', and ':'. But It seems that backslash is only used in '['. So, ']' and ']' are not considered as a special character, right?

Comment: "]" is not a special character *unless* it is preceded by unescaped "[". I've added an explanation in my answer. BTW in my previous answer I put a backslash in the REPLACEMENT to escape
"[", which is unnecessary. I have updated my answer. BR.